# How to connect to a server through eclipse plugin and perform operations

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, client-server

I am writing an eclipse plugin using java as language. The plugin is an interface to a tool present in the server. The user writes text in eclipse. The server should parse it and give an output. This should be displayed back in eclipse.

The above simple steps must be performed by my application. Currently, I have the backend tool to parse is ready. The front-end in eclipse has a dummy GUI ready. My problem is with connection between the server and eclipse plugin.

How can I send text in eclipse (say when a user presses a button present in the interface) to the server. I know the server details and like server address on the LAN and userid/password.

Which interfaces/ what type of programming should i use to accomplish this.

**EDIT:**

Here is how i run my command on the server:

```
mycommand -f [filename] [optional arguments]
```

My frontend has the GUI ready in eclipse to form the `[optional arguments]` part. Now i have to send the text to `mycommand` and get its output.

Comment: What kind of server is that ?

Comment: What's the protocol used by the server? UDP? TCP? HTTP? RMI?

Comment: @AviramSegal internal LAN server??? (i think :P but i am ignorant). I can connect to it using `telnet` command in `cmd` (command prompt) on windows. server address is of the format myMachine@somedomain.com

Comment: @JBNizet ... How can i find that out? I am noob with this. I use the popular `putty` application to connect to it. I use the `telnet` option

Comment: @AviramSegal yeh pretty much. But i can also use FTP on it (have tried this out)... havent tried other commands tho.

Comment: delete my comment by mistake, i asked if he wants to run a command on a telnet server

Comment: @AviramSegal asked wether it was Windows server or Linux server. Also, what JBNIZET asked is vital to answering your question.
If you don't know the answers to these 2 questions, go and ASK then!

Comment: @AdelBoutros my server is a Linux server.

Comment: and the protocol you would like to use for client-server communication is ?

Comment: @AdelBoutros I am ignorent at the protocol part. I dont know about this. How can i find out which protocol to use?

Comment: @footy If you are alone on this project, then google RMI, TCP, UDP and decide. Then, and only then we can help you

Comment: @AdelBoutros Ok. And yeh i am alone in this. I will do that.

Comment: @AdelBoutros yeh I am making progress. I think i am figuring out how to do it bit by bit through the RMI method. Since i am still learning guess it make take a while till i put together somecode and test it actually. :)

Comment: @footy But don't forget to accept the answer that will have helped you eventually

Comment: @AdelBoutros yep, I do that delegently. :D Only for 2 questions till now i havent found a satisfactory answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send/recieve messages, I would recommend you use Java RMI which is easy to implement.

Here's a tutorial on setting up the client and the server:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html

Comment: Thanks :) I will lookinto it and update after going through and trying it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [TelnetClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html) from [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) to connect to the `telnet` server and do something